# How can I add a contextListener in logback groovy configuration?

Tags: logback

I want to use LevelChangePropagator as logback contextListener, as described in the [logback manual](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/configuration.html#contextListener). However in my project logback is configured using groovy, and there's nothing in the official documentation about configuring contextListener in groovy. Logback provides a tool to [translate xml configuration](http://logback.qos.ch/translator/asGroovy.html) into a groovy configuration. I tried it, but it just skipped the contextListener part.

I've found exactly [one answer](http://mailman.qos.ch/pipermail/logback-user/2012-February/003011.html) to my question in the logback mailing lists, but solution doesn't seem to be working for me.

**EDIT:**
I've created an issue in logback JIRA about missing documentation: http://jira.qos.ch/browse/LOGBACK-979. Still, maybe someone knows the answer?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add this to logback.groovy:

```
import ch.qos.logback.classic.jul.LevelChangePropagator

def lcp = new LevelChangePropagator()
lcp.context = context
lcp.resetJUL = true
context.addListener(lcp)
```